# How to remove global flag from variable in workspace

Tags: matlab, global-variables

I have some data (.mat) which was set to global as it was saved and which is now saved as a global cell. When I load it into the workspace it automatically is set to global.

Is there a way to remove the global flag from this variable, without removing the variable itself from the workspace, only the global attribute?

When I copy this array it automatically copies its global attribute as well and in the [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html) it only says how to set to global and not how to remove it. I am using MATLAB R2015a.

```
global exportmat
exportmat = cell(889,12);
filename = 'test.mat';
save(filename)

clear -globals exportmat

load('test.mat')
whos

  Name              Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  exportmat       889x12            85344  cell     global
```

Comment: I quite heavily edited your question, please roll it back if you don't agree. My motivation is that removing the `global` attribute from a variable is actually not straight forward, nor easy to find online, and that that is a good fit Stack Overflow. However, your initial question ended up being "not reproducible", which is off-topic here and thus the question would be closed. That's why I opted to generalise it a bit to keep it here.

Comment: @Adriaan : there now are two `load` commands in this code snippet. Is this as intended? Also, does `clear exportmat` cleat the global, or only the local reference to it? (I don’t use them a lot, so am no sure about this.) A `clear globals` would make it more obvious what is going on.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I removed the second `load`, it was indeed superfluous, thanks. I made the `clear` call explicit by removing both the `-global` and the variable itself. If I understand the docs on `clear` correctly, `clear A` only deletes the copy in the current workspace indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest method, RAM permitting, I could find was to simply redeclare it:

```
global A
A=3;
whos A
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  A         1x1                 8  double    global    
B=A;
whos B
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  B         1x1                 8  double               % Note: not global
clear -global
A=B;
clear B;
whos A
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  A         1x1                 8  double
```

If you need this variable more often, simply use this to remove the `global` flag and save it again.

Using `save` and `load` on R2016b:

```
global exportmat
exportmat = cell(889,12);
filename = 'test.mat';
save(filename)

clear exportmat
load('test.mat')
% whos exportmat

exportmat2=exportmat;

whos

  Name              Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  exportmat       889x12            85344  cell     global    
  exportmat2      889x12            85344  cell               
  filename          1x8                16  char
```

If R2015a doesn't work for cells (I can't check that since I don't have that version), you can reassign each cell contents, which should work if they contain doubles:

```
B = cell(size(A));
for ii = 1:size(B,1)
    for jj = 1:size(B,2)
        tmp = A{ii,jj};
        B{ii,jj} = tmp;
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, your code works for me but if I apply it to my variable it is copied with the global attribute and also my redeclared variable has the global attribute. 'whos exportmat
  Name             Size                Bytes  Class    Attributes

  exportmat      889x12            457696722  cell     global    

>> exportmat2=exportmat;
>> whos exportmat2
  Name              Size                Bytes  Class    Attributes

  exportmat2      889x12            457696722  cell     global'

Comment: @C.B. please edit your question containing sample data where this actually happens, as I can't see your screen to see what happens. Note that using `A=A;` instead indeed results in retaining the `global` attribute, so using a temporary variable is necessary. For me it works for `cell` type variables as well.

Comment: @C.B. I'm afraid it might be a version-specific problem, as with `cell` type variables this trick works in my 2016b version. I'll look around for a bit.

Comment: Thanks; I tried to use global on a cell type variable in my Version and it does not work. It actually removes the global flag from a double if I convert this variable into a cell